# Invalid contract attribute for IMetadataExchange

Tags: wcf

I have upgraded a WCF Service to .NET Framework 4.5.  After doing so I noticed a blue squiggly line around the `IMetaDataExchange` in the host config file.

This is what the services section of the config looks like:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="MyServiceHost">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="noSecurityBinding" contract="MyServiceContract"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

When I hover the mouse over `IMetadataExchange` the error says:

> The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'IMetadataExchange' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

The service seems to work fine.  So I am curious why is this invalid.

Comment: Recompile the interface project then restart Visual Studio. Like all Microsoft products, sometimes you just have to reboot.

Answer (score 53):

Can you delete .SUO (solution Users Option file) file after closing VS? This will reset the cache for XMLEditor component in VS and will fix your problem.

Comment: This worked for me again, I agree with BFOT, this answer should be markes as the answer..

Comment: This worked for me just now. Nothing beats an old post that helps you.

Comment: Worked for me in VS.NET 2012

Comment: Where can I find that .suo file? I can't find it there where .sln is. EDIT: found it - it's hidden file.

Comment: +1 works! (even though now I don't get this hover error message even when I put in a faulty value.. hmm)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work for a few minutes.  Then if you exit or give the background compiler a chance to catch up, it appears again.  Temporary relief only.

Comment: Not a solution for me, as already said, it's like when you're cleaning the solution, doesn't actually solve the problem

Answer (score 18):

I added System.ServiceModel to the references for the project and it went away

Comment: Funny enough, I deleted the ServiceModel and it went away.

Comment: Somehow this worked for me. I add this in my service host project. Clean solution and rebuild solution.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem to this - several `name` and `contract` attributes showing in the App.Config of my WCF Service with the dreaded blue squiggly, and warnings showing up in the Error List.

In my case the problem was that after creating the services and contracts I had refactored the namespaces of the service project, so the generated solution-specific *.xsd was using the new namespaces but my refactoring tool hadn't updated the App.Config with the changes. Going in and adding the fully-specified namespaces fixed the issue.

Comment: Absolutely, apparently it's the VS2012 way of notifying you that the type specified cannot be found in any of the referenced assemblies - super helpful (but the displayed message is somewhat cryptic I must admit)

Comment: Going in to what to add the fully specified namespaces?

Comment: Going into the app.config to fully-qualify the namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps not the answer for the OP, but others with this problem should check that `[ServiceContract]` is declared for the `interface` of your services, because this produces the exact error.

Answer (score 3):

IF you running Intellisense on the warning. It will bring up a list for you to choose from you can Explicitly call that member.

Answer (score 3):

If deleting the .SUO file doesn't work, check your references to ensure that you have the System.ServiceModel reference.  That ended up being the issue that brought me here.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a possible cause. Adding the reference fixed the error in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem to be that the contract attribute is case sensitive.

I had a different solution that referenced the same service, but did not have any warnings in the app.config. i ran compare in notepad++ on the system.serviceModel section of the app.config and it highlighted the difference in case between the two contract attributes.

as soon as i modified the contract attribute to the correct case sensitive spelling the warning went away instantly

Answer (score 1):

Closing VS2013 Prof, removing the "obj" folder and recompiling has done the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
If you ever change your C# class in Service1.cs and IService1.cs. Also update the name attribute in the service element "<namespace>.<classname>" and contract attribute in the endpoind element "<namespace>.<classname>" in your App.config.

BTW. sorry for the bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on client side. For me the solution was to delete and add the service reference again.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you lost your references when you upgraded the project? I noticed this error when my project containing my client had no reference to my project with my service.