# The value is invalid according to its datatype 'clientcontracttype'

Tags: wcf, endpoint, contract

I am getting an error message saying:

> The contract attribute is invalid. the value is invalid according to
>   its datatype 'clientcontracttype'

Following is the endpoint configuration in web.config of this WCF application. I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012.
I have verified the contract `OnlineReporting.Core.Contracts.IReportingInternalWcfPortal` is already there.

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:63817/ReportingInternalWcfPortal.svc" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" 
          contract="OnlineReporting.Core.Contracts.IReportingInternalWcfPortal" 
          name="ReportingInternalPortal" />
```

Comment: Experienced same problem I looked at similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12408667/1456174) and after rebuild it was ok.

Comment: It's not worth putting in an answer but make sure you don't have a typo in your `App.config` file. My service contract interface was declared as `Endpoint` while I had `EndPoint` in the config file ^_^'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I see this question is pretty old and I don't know if you have found a solution by now, but just in case, this is what I have found will resolve:

1) In the Solution Explorer, under the Service References folder, right-click the service reference name with the issue and select 'Configure Service Reference'.

2) The Service Reference Settings window will appear. Uncheck the box labeled 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' and click the OK button.

3) Rebuild the project.

After rebuilding, the warning should disappear.

Comment: In VB.NET, this is under MyProject->WCFOptions->Advanced... and it is only relevant when using DataContractSerializer option (XML is the default).  Just an FYI.

Comment: Isn't this rebuilding the types from the service as opposed to using the "real" assembly types?  I would imagine this could become a maintenance issue.

Answer (score 23):

I found this question looking for the same error on a web service project.

In my case this error happened when I forgot to add the `[ServiceContract]` attribute on the `IServiceBase` interface.

As soon as I added it in the error went away.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceBase
    {
        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<ListItem> GetListItems();

        [OperationContract]
        void SaveListItems(IEnumerable<ListItem> listItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

The same error occurs when you're missing a reference [in the project with the .config] to the actual project/library containing the interface/service contract...

Answer (score 3):

In my case I changed the Service Contract by unwittingly removing an interface which was key to the Service Contract.

Weeks later I found a broken client with an out of date service reference.  Since the removal of the interface was in error I put it back in.

Another possible resolution would be to have rebuild the service reference to match the new service contract (in my case would have broken the project build since the referenced interface had been removed).

Thanks to OrangeKing89 for pointing me in the right direction.  I knew there was the potential of the Service Contract being changed.

Comment: Yes this is an old thread - but I found the warning about this in Visual Studio annoying and thought I would fix my build.  The "selected answer" had the uncheck reuse types - that broke the build entirely. I had to reset that. I checked the service Contract it was there, and I checked that there were references to the project with the Contact - that was there. This answer made me think and look again - I had changed the namespace on the project  when doing  ReUse uncheck- then I saw the issue - the Endpoint had the original namespace in front of the Interface name - fixed the namespace. done.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a naming conflict.

When you add a service reference, visual studio generates a client class as a proxy which implements the contract, the default name for that proxy is the name of the service appended by "Client" so if your service is "MyService" the client class would be "MyServiceClient".

My problem was that my project name was "MyServiceClient" ! which caused this conflict.

Comment: Microsoft **trying** to help you out again

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old thread, but in my case, the issue was that someone had at one time added a service reference to the project, and then decided to take another route, but the entry remained in web.config, so just deleting that entry in web.config solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is ancient, however I ran into the same problem with C# and Visual Studio 2017. Everything was working and compiling fine, then it was not. I downgraded from .Net 4.6.2 to 4.6, as SQLite v108 does not support 108, then I received this error and others. It took me a bit of time to trace a solution. I did not see my solution anywhere, so I thought that I place it out there for the future.

I deleted my service reference, checked in all my changes to TFS, and then added back the service reference. I then built the solution and all was fine again.

I checked the app.config and other files and all seemed fine, just did not build. Obviously, VS2017 introduces .Net version information somewhere but not obviously.

Hopefully, my solution helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If boths services are included in the same solution, you only have to perform two actions, providing that both services are working.

- Add the reference to the project which contains the webserver you need. Do it from the "Projects" tab.
- Configure your main service web.config like this:

  ```
  <services>
    <service name="MyCurrentProject.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ConfigRest">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restServicehttp" name="RestEndpoint" bindingName="webHttpBinding" contract="MyCurrentProject.Service"/>
    </service>
    <service name="AnotherPoject.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ConfigRest">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restServicehttp" name="RestEndpoint" bindingName="webHttpBinding" contract="AnotherPoject.Service"/>
    </service>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that the code was correct, the interface had the correct [ServiceContract] tag, and the .config endpoint had the correct interface namespace, but the project with the interface needed to be recompiled so that the other project that had the .config file would get an up to date .dll of the first project within its bin folder. So recompile the code is the answer to make visual studio happy.