# Contract attribute is invalid

Tags: wcf, web-config

I have been reaching this for a few hours now. I am getting this error message:

The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The Value 'AddressService.IAddressVerificationService' is invalid according to it's datatype 'clientContractType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

and the config file looks like this:

```
<endpoint address="http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerificationService"
           contract="AddressService.IAddressVerificationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerificationService" />
```

My Service beginning looks like:

```
namespace AddressVerificationWCF
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.

[ServiceContract]
public interface IAddressVerificationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Address VerifyThisAddress(string stuff);
}
```

}

I have tried numerous things like changing the names, deleting files, etc. but am scratching my head AGAIN.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The contract needs to be the fully-qualified name of the interface - usually the namespace that contains the interface, plus the interface name.  Looking at your posted code this should be:

```
AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService
```

So your config would look like:

```
<endpoint address="http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerificationService"
          contract="AddressVerificationWCF.IAddressVerificationService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerificationService" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I think it's more than that because of how it's compiled. I think I am better off doing it this way, however, I am getting a new error now. Could be an IIS issue maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283787/access-is-denied-when-creating-connection-to-wcf-service

Comment: "The contract needs to be the fully-qualified name of the interface" - actually it needs to be the `ServiceContractAttribute.ConfigurationName`, which by default is the fully-qualified name of the interface, but can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

[The value is invalid according to its datatype 'clientcontracttype'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497378/the-value-is-invalid-according-to-its-datatype-clientcontracttype)

In above Vincent Van Den Berghe suggested below that solved my issue. Credits to Vincent...

> The same error occurs when you're missing a reference [in the project
> with the .config] to the actual project/library containing the
> interface/service contract...

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I ran my VS 2012 in administrator mode and it solved it.