# Access is denied when creating connection to wcf service

Tags: wcf

I have the following code:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://www.verifythisaddress.com/AddressVerification/AddressVerificationService.svc");
            BasicHttpBinding serviceBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            serviceBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            serviceBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);

            AddressService.IAddressVerificationService client = new AddressService.AddressVerificationServiceClient(serviceBinding,endpointAddress);
            AddressService.Address verifiedAddress = null;
```

When I run this code using a client application everything works fine, but when I run it in another application, same exact code. I am getting "Access is Denied" error. Could this be an IIS issue? My question is why does it work for a windows form application, but not for another.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you describe as the differences between the two applications, we could give you a hint. Are they both custom made C#? Are they both run as the same user? Do they use the exact same target web service? Was the web service reference created in the same way for both applications?

Comment: Hi Pantelis, the one that works is a windows application that I use for testing. The other one is Nopcommerce that I believe packages everything up in a dll. Granted, the Nopcommerce I am using is local with full code so I wouldn't think it matters since it's not a dll yet. However, I have just moved everything to a hosting server which makes me believe that maybe IIS needs to be configured. Maybe to be an application and check the permissions on there.