# The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value 'ServiceSoap' is invalid according to its datatype 'clientContractType'

Tags: c#, soap

Can someone help me navigate how to solve this problem? [click here for snip showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j44yp.jpg)

I am new to soap stuff, and am migrating some code from one solution to another, and I don't know where to start to solve this problem.  I've done hours of research, and it *seems* like maybe it's an issue with references.  The project builds, but I have this warning, and then the innerexception I end up getting when I try this:

_mm = new ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap", endpoint.AbsoluteUri.ToString());

is a System.NullReferenceException error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982083/4228458

Comment: @CodingYoshi, thank you.  That is one I tried.  I do not have any service references.  And there aren't any in the project where this works (where I'm migrating the code from).