# Adding a wcf ajax enabled file to web forms in asp produces a validation error

Tags: ajax, wcf

I am trying to create a project that uses wcf(ajax enabled) as a communication framework with an ASP.Net project.

When I add a new wcf file to my project an error appears in my configuration file. I have saved my project as Demo and my service file is called Employeeservice.svc.

For details of my configuration file, please read. The error occurs around the  tag and the error message reports:

The name attribute is invalid The value employee demoservice is invalid according to it's datatype servicenametype - the enumeration constraint failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Demo.EmployeeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Demo.EmployeeService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Demo.EmployeeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Demo.EmployeeService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The error occurs around the tag <service name="Demo.EmployeeService">

Answer (score 0):

This should be a warning not an error, it does not affect the build of the project. On my side, my configuration is basically the same as yours, but it's just a warning, and the project can be built normally. Are you creating projects with older versions of `VS`? If it's `VS2012`, I suggest you delete the solution `.SUO` file and rebuild the project, which should solve the problem.
[Invalid contract attribute for IMetadataExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408667/invalid-contract-attribute-for-imetadataexchange)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.